# spark worker is receiving job but does not start working

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I use this compose-file to create a local spark "cluster"

```
version: "3"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: spark:3.5.0
    entrypoint: /opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
   
  spark-worker:
    image: spark:3.5.0
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    entrypoint: /opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
```

afterwards i use a conda environment to connect to the spark cluster from my host machine

```
name: spark
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pyspark
  - jupyter
```

however when i open a notebook and run the following command, i can see that there is a new application in my spark web ui. But it does not seem to be doing anything.

```
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("spark://localhost:7077").getOrCreate()
spark.range(1000 * 1000 * 1000).count()
```

when i check the logs of my worker i see that it received somthing. But it does not do anything.

```
23/09/22 10:06:19 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=55497" "-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false" "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED" "-Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@example.net:55497" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "172.28.0.4" "--cores" "10" "--app-id" "app-20230922100619-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.28.0.4:41199" "--resourceProfileId" "0"
```

any idea what is wrong here?